# How to check for user login for first time in that month - MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a Budgeting Application in Asp.Net MVC 5 and I am making a history log for all the transactions and budgets that are created. I have made the models for it and they are working but I am trying to have the budgets and transactions reset at the beginning of the month. I have it so that if the user logs in on the first day of the month then it will reset. But I got to thinking that if the user doesn't log in on the first day of the month then the logic in my controller won't work. How can I check to see if it's the first time a user logs in for that month even if it's the second or the 15th day of the month and if it's the first time for the month then do the actions that result in storing the old data and resetting it for the beginning of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know when was the last time that the user logged in.

If the last time was in a month other than the current month, then this is the first login of this user in this month.

Edit: one way to do this is a database table column "LastLoginDate" that you set on login using a `DateTime.Now` or in the dB using GetDate() or similar SQL

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I just added a new column in my AspNetUsers to have a column of LastLogIn and I can now compare that to the DateTime.Now when they log in and if the months are different then I will run the logic. So helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, and I thank @JeremyThompson for editing my question to add something to it.  Stackoverflow is supposed to work like that, but very few people play along.